# How much of The French Mistake was based on fact?

Tags: supernatural

In the *Supernatural* episode ["The French Mistake"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1627712/?ref_=ttep_ep15) (S6E15), Sam and Dean are zapped into our universe, wherein they are really Jared Padalecki and Jensen Ackles, actors playing Sam and Dean Winchester on the show Supernatural.

We know that Jared and Genevieve (Ruby) are really married, but is any of the other stuff (specifically the feud between Jared and Jensen) true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the IMDB trivia page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1627712/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv):

> In the alternate universe, "Jared" and "Jensen" don't talk to each other. In real life, they are best friends and were each other's groomsmen.

In this video they tell their story of their first time meeting, and they play off each other really well. They seem like good mates just off this alone

[This Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/How-much-of-the-Supernatural-episode-The-French-Mistake-is-true) also shows some of the different truths that happened during the episode:

> When Misha was seen tweeting on his phone, they were actually real tweets that were posted
>
> The wedding photo of Jared was a real life genuine one.
>
> The magazine that was shown in Jensen's trailer was an authentic copy of The Official Supernatural Magazine, Issue 11

[Jensen actually does have](https://twitter.com/bodyguard4jandj/status/382660836294012928) an RC helicopter

[image]

Comment: also, I believe they show legitimate former roles for both actors.

Comment: But does Jared actually have a jacuzzi, and does Jensen really have an RC helicopter in his trailer?

Comment: @Gallifreyan, to answer your second question [I give you](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/35/ac/68/35ac68e073e575ce51594aa3c1e3657b.jpg)

Comment: This deserves to be in the answer! :D (I mean it)

Comment: Excellent answer.  Also, never even thought to actually read the IMDB page.